# Copy the row data and Paste to another sheet when criteria match in google sheet with App Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am having Fleet maintenance google sheet in that i need to copy and Paste the data to another sheet when criteria match.

When Service Status in Data sheet Equal to "Service Pre Alert" or "Service Alert" or "Expired" any of these that row should copy and paste to output sheet with selected column and date stamp. it is possible with app script.

Note : Data sheet, Service status column will update auto when ever HMR reading is updated, so it will do repeated process.

Spreadsheet Link:
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1UkPGyBFTXUAtlpGmdEDLYo0p1G-tAazjjCFMsu2FqgM/edit?usp=sharing

Thanks in Advance

Johnn

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function alert2() {
  // with integration of the extra column
  var sh1 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
  var sh2 = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Output2");
  var output = []
  if (sh1.getLastRow() == 1) { return }
  if (sh2.getLastRow() > 2) { 
    output = sh2.getRange(2, 1, sh2.getLastRow() - 1, sh2.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(e => (e[12] == "Completed"))
    sh2.getRange('A2:L'+(sh2.getLastRow())).clearContent()
  }
  var data = sh1.getRange(2, 1, sh1.getLastRow() - 1, sh1.getLastColumn()).getValues().filter(e => (e[14] == "Expired" || e[14] == "Service Alert" || e[14] == "Service Pre Alert"))
  try {
    data.forEach(function(r){
      var alertData = []
      r.forEach((c, col) => {
        if (col<=9 || col==14) alertData.push(c);
      })
      alertData.push(new Date())
      var workSatus = r[14] == 'Expired' ? 'Pending' : 'Service due'
      alertData.push(workSatus)
      output.push(alertData)
    });
  } catch (e) { }
  sh2.getRange(2,1,output.length,output[0].length).setValues(output)
}
```

Comment: Its working but creating duplicate event when i run script 2 or 3 time, i have changed little bit in format.I added one column in output sheet 'Work Status' in that when ever 'Service Status' equal to "Expired"  it should generate automatically "Pending " in  Work Status column ,simultaneously for "Service Pre Alert" & "Service Alert" equal to "Service Due".
When run script Copy and paste the data from 'Data' sheet above said and should not create duplicate untill i edit the 'Work Status' to "Completed" after completion job .

Comment: Their is no duplicate now, i mention comments on spreadsheet pls check it, my requirement  process to be repeated when job is completed.

Comment: Point 1. when work status became Completed, leave them as is in the output tab 2 to maintain the History.
Point 2. if service status has not been changed in the data, theses rows have to appear one again Correct.

Comment: done, let me know if now it is ok and if i have well undestood your needs.

Comment: Yes working. some correction is required
Point 1. created date column in output sheet  is getting update,  i need created date when the job copy and paste.
Point 2 .when adding the column in output sheet is getting error. 
Exception: The number of columns in the data does not match the number of columns in the range. The data has 13 but the range has 17.

Comment: the problem of date is the same as here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71514044/appscript-giving-different-date-than-given-in-google-sheet/71514900#71514900 , your script settings were wrong! Check if now it is correct (GMT+05:30?).

Comment: Great Work almost completed. only created date having problem.  Condition is when ever the data is copy and paste to another sheet first time, date generated should not change. when script trigger. Now whats happening when i run the script/trigger the date and time getting current value.

Comment: Neither the date nor the time changed after running the script for rows that were declared "completed"

Comment: What is your locale? GB, India? you have to put the same value in spreadsheet and script editor.